# Problem of running multiple browsers simultaneously

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, multiprocess

Hi i tried to use multiprocessor to open browsers simultaneously, but it came out sequentially. May i know what are the problems in my code?

```
def multiple_browser(sub_link):
    browser.get(sub_link)
    browser.maximize_window()
    print('done')
if __name__ == '__main__':
for i in range(len(link)):
    p = Process(target=multiple_browser, args=(link[i],))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to not use `join()` in for-loop. Just do it this way,

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    processes = []
    for i in range(len(link)):
        p = Process(target=multiple_browser, args=(link[i],))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

This initiates all the processes first, and later on, `join()` waits for the completion of all of them.